# how to upload file and store it in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, file-upload, gridfs

in this example "path" is path to (uploaded)temporary file in server? or file path in client's device? i'm reading files metadata from $_FILES but don't know where to read the file to store in db. please help. (sorry for my english)

```
<?php
    // connect to the ‘myGrid’ GridFS
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->myDB;
    $myGrid = $db->getGridFS('myGrid');
    $some_file='path of your video or audio file';
    // some extra data you may want to store with your file
    $data_array = array(
        'mime' => mime_content_type($some_file),
        'timestamp' => time(),
    );

    // store a file into the GridFS
    $myGrid->storeFile($some_file, $data_array);
?>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['foo']['tmp_name']` is the location where PHP has TEMPORARILY stored the file on the server. But be warned: storing files in a DB is generally a bad idea, and has very few usage cases that justify it.

Comment: for a file(file < 30mb) sharing service it's a bad idea?

Comment: doesn't matter how big/small. if you want to protect direct access to the files, then just don't put them inside your side's document root. putting them into the db is a huge waste - consider 100 people all downloading the same file - you have to suck the SAME file out of your database 100 times.

Comment: @MarcB probably shouldn't bog a newbie down in that just yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the path to whatever file your putting in, in this case it will be the `tmp_name` path from PHP `$_FILES` array

Comment: it works on small files, but when trying to upload bigger, for example(10mb) file, error occurred

Comment: @MherDidaryan you need to setup PHP to allow bigger files: http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/ first result on google

Comment: thank you very much. i'm new to php, i didn't know that there is a limit